# bash string substitution returns input for non-matching part

Tags: bash

Assume the following function in bash:

```
jj() { echo "${1#*=}"; }
```

Here are two invocations, and their respective results:

```bash
$ jj -d=1
1

$ jj -d
-d
```

Now, this is standard bash behavior for parameter/variable substitution, and works as designed.

**Expected**: I'd like the substitution expression to return an empty string, when there is no "=" in the input of $1, and return the part after the "=" otherwise. Can this be done in one expression?

**Context**: in a script I maintain, I'd like to extend the CLI parser to pass the string after an "="-option as an argument, otherwise no/an empty argument shall be passed to the called function. Here's the relevant excerpt:

```bash
while [[ "$#" -gt 0 ]]; do
    case $1 in
        -h=*|--help=*|-h|--help)              print_help "${1#*=}";;
        -p=*|--processes=*|-p|--processes)    bootstrap_processes "${1#*=}";;
        -v=*|--validate=*|-v|--validate)      validate_models "${1#*=}";;
        *) printf "%s\n\n" "Unknown parameter passed: $1"; __print_help; exit 2 ;;
    esac
    shift
done
```

And no, I don't want to use/switch to any form of GNU/Bash opt parsing ;).

I'd also like to maintain the neatness/compactness of my current approach. I've tried some "IFS/read()/array[]/mapfile/substitutions-in-substitutions" approaches, but came out empty-handed.

**Difficulties**: I didn't quite figure out how to search for this probably trivial challenge on the Internet, and the suggestions of other proposed questions on the Stack Overflow universe did not reveal any useful help.

Comment: The output of `jj -d=1` is `-d`, not `1` and it is correct. `${1#=*}` produces the output described in the question.

Comment: Regarding "the part after the "=" otherwise" - the part after which `=`, the first or the last or something else, e.g. given input like `var='foo=bar'` what should the output be?

Comment: You said "I don't want to use/switch to any form of GNU/Bash opt parsing" but are you also ruling out the POSIX standard [getopts](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/getopts.html)?

Comment: @EdMorton: not if the resulting code looks more concise/neat, and increases flexibility, stability, and correctness without significantly more lines of code.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
shopt -s extglob
jj() { printf '%s\n' "${1##*([^=])?(=)}"; }
```

- `shopt -s extglob` enables "extended globbing" (including patterns like `*([^=])?(=)`).  See the [extglob](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) section in [glob - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob).  It's generally safe to have `extglob` always turned on in Bash programs.  See [Is it dangerous to always have extglob on?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/276911/264812).
- See the accepted, and excellent, answer to [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/264812) for an explanation of why I replaced `echo` with `printf`.

Comment: Yep, this works too. Thank you very much. And also for the additional pointers on `printf`, which I normally always use in my scripts.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear (to me) if OP wants an actual empty-string/blank-line generated on a non-match, or no output.

Assuming 'no ouput' ... one idea using a regex and the `BASH_REMATCH` (system) array:

```
jj() { [[ "$1" =~ .*=([^=]*$) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; }
```

**NOTES:**

- the first part of the regex matches up to the 'last' `=` and then ...
- the capture group (contents within the parens - `([^=]*$)`) says to match on everything that's not a `=` character up to the end of the input (`$`)
- since we only have one capture group the desired value is in the array entry with an index of `1`
- add `typeset -p BASH_REMATCH` (after the comparison) to see the contents of the array
- on a failed match (ie, `.*=`, in particular the `=`, does not match) the `&& echo ...` is not executed

Taking for a test drive:

```
$ jj -d=1
1
$ jj -d
$
```

Notice that the `jj -d` returns nothing ... no empty string, no blank line; though if you were to capture this 'output' in a variable (eg, `x=$(jj -d)`) then you would in fact end up with an empty variable (ie, `x=""`).

If OP really does want an empty-field/blank-line then we could extend this as such:

```
$ jj() { [[ "$1" =~ .*=([^=]*$) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" || echo ""; }
                                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Taking for a test drive:

```
$ jj -d=1
1
$ jj -d
             <<<=== empty-string/blank-line
$
```

Comment: Thank you @mark-fuso! I indeed wanted to return nothing. So, your first approach is just perfect. Now, to incorporate it into my script context, I did `-p=*|--processes=*|-p|--processes)   bootstrap_processes $([[ "$1" =~ .*=([^=]*$) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}");;`, which is a bit ugly, but works.

Comment: @ikaerom since it appears you want to implement this logic in multiple locations I'd probably opt to *a)* wrap the logic in a function (eg, `jj()`), *b)* then pre-calculate and save the value in a variable (`val=$(jj "$1")`, then *c)* reference the value in your `case` statements, eg,  `print_help "$val"` / `bootstrap_processes "$val"` 
 / `valdate_models "$val"` ... not quite as *ugly* and should still work; you could eliminate the subshell (`$(jj "$1")`) via *a)* a hard-coded variable name in the function or *b)* setting a dynamic variable via a nameref (in the function)

Comment: The regexp is more likely to be `[^=]*=(.*)` so that given input like `var='foo=bar'` it matches to the first `=` rather than  the last one so the function can output `'foo=bar'` instead of `var='foo`.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW here's how I'd write the parser for an interface similar to what you're trying to use:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while getopts :h:p:v:HPV-: opt; do
    arg="${OPTARG}"
    if [[ "$opt" == '-' ]] && [[ "$arg" =~ ([^=]+)(=(.*))? ]]; then
        opt="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        arg="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
    fi
    case "$opt" in
        h|H|help )      echo print_help "$arg" ;;
        p|P|processes ) echo bootstrap_processes "$arg" ;;
        v|V|validate )  echo validate_models "$arg" ;;
        :  ) printf 'Missing argument to short option: -%s\n' "$arg"; exit 2 ;;
        \? ) printf 'Invalid short option: -%s\n' "$arg"; exit 2 ;;
        *  ) printf 'Invalid long option: --%s\n' "$arg"; exit 2 ;;
    esac
done
shift $(( OPTIND - 1 ))

echo "remaining script args: $*"
```

I can't tell for sure from your code which long options you intend to have mandatory vs optional arguments, nor which short options should have mandatory vs no arguments so the above is just guessing at some of that to give you the idea of how to structure the option parsing. You may, for example, end up wanting to separate `v`, `V`, `validate` into separate cases for different argument parsing and error handling, I don't know. I created 3 separate prints for different types of error handling just to show you can, obviously you don't need to do that if you don't want to.

I say similar because I would not allow short options that can take assignments (`-v=`), nor would I allow short options that sometimes take arguments and sometimes don't as that's not the way Unix utility interfaces normally work - if they did how could you tell if `-pv` was equivalent to 2 options, `-p -v` or one option plus an argument to that option `-p 'v'`. [POSIX allows it](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html), but it requires you to never put white space between an option and it's argument (you can do `-pfoo` but not `-p foo`) and never put a series of options together after a `-` (e.g. `-pv`) so it's messy/cludgy and best avoided.

In the above `-v whatever` is equivalent to your `-v=whatever` while `-V` (upper case) is equivalent to your `-v` (lower case) alone, assuming you want to support that construct, and similarly for `-H` and `-P`.

You can call the above as:

```
$ ./tst.sh -p foo -vbar -PV --validate='this or that' -H -- file1 -v file2
bootstrap_processes foo
validate_models bar
bootstrap_processes
validate_models
validate_models this or that
print_help
remaining script args: file1 -v file2
```

and note that:

- The interface looks like a normal Unix command,
- The problem you asked about of splitting at `=` is solved (you'd have to add code to your current script to handle that),
- Thanks to `getopts`, `-PV` (2 options combined), `-vbar` (no space between option and argument), and `--` (the end of options flag) all work as they should with no extra code (you'd have to add code to your current script to handle that too).

Per your criteria that you'd consider `getopts` [if the resulting code looks more concise/neat, and increases flexibility, stability, and correctness without significantly more lines of code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77518575/bash-string-substitution-returns-input-for-non-matching-part/77519344#comment136661635_77518575) , the above code compared to the code you'd end up with otherwise once you add the code you asked about to split at `=` and the other currently missing standard Unix utility interface functionality.:

- Is almost certainly more concise/neat (compared to the extra code needed otherwise, definitely not less concise/neat).
- Increases flexibility (users can combine options, can have space or not between option and argument, and/or can add arguments that look like options after `--` with no extra code),
- Is more stable (will work for more ways users would expect to be able to call it given how other commands work and won't confuse file names with options).
- Is more correct (does not violate the POSIX utilities interface standard as `-v=..` would).
- Is almost certainly fewer lines of code (definitely not significantly more).

so best I can tell that satisfies all of your criteria.

Comment: Thank you, @Ed Morton, for your time and dedication in writing this answer. I had for brevity only given a part of my parser, and I'm inclined to post the whole thing (if that does not violate the rules of Stack Overflow). It's a bit more twisted than that. However, the most important part, which my approach allows, given all the excellent and valid points you mention, is that option to submit the following: `cli.sh -p=p1,p2,p5,a{1..3} --validate=1,2,5 --processes=p3,p4 -p -v`. In your example, the first option would be without the "=", but still does not work in the same expected way.

Comment: You're welcome. If you post a new question with it's own [mcve] that shows what the expected behavior is for `-p p1,p2,p5,a{1..3}` and what it actually does instead I'll be happy to take a look. If the issue is that you can't have both `-p p1,p2,p5,a{1..3}` and `-p` without arguments - that's by design, don't allow short options with optional arguments or you can't allow spaces between options and their arguments.